# Bash if grep or grep elif grep? So confused

Tags: bash, if-statement, grep

Here is what I am trying to do. I want to grep(maybe?) a file for keywords based on what I find do blah.

```
if grep "env=" does not exist OR "env=" exists but is null file.name; then
env=prod 
elif grep "env=dev" OR "env=qa" file.name; then
env=dev/qa respectivly
```

I was trying some grep command but was getting stuck with that

Not sure if this gets it yet, still need to test

```
if ! grep -q -E "^environment=" "${__file}" | grep -q -e "dev|qa|prod"; then
    if [ -n "${ENV}" ]; then
      echo "environment=${ENV}" >> "${__file}"
    else
      echo "environment=prod" >> "${__file}"
    fi
  fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [source](https://ss64.com/bash/source.html) command. Put all local variables in file named `local_env.sh`.

sample content of `local_env.sh`:

```
environment=dev
```

Now you can create a script:

```
source env.sh
# if environment is empty string set it to prod
[ -z "${environment}" ] && environment=prod
echo ${environment}
```